# Openshift idle a service using REST API

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, openshift-client-tools, openshift-enterprise

Is there a way to idle an OCP service using the Openshift REST API ?

I know, that every oc command that runs from the client hits an api to perform the action requested.

However - I don't see an information about the endpoint to call to idle a service in the Openshift API Documentation.

Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: The `oc idle` command actually gets pods for the endpoint, gets to the associated DeploymentConfig via replication controller, stores the scale into annotations and scales it down. You can see the series of associated REST API calls when running the command with high `loglevel` such as `oc idle <endpoint> --loglevel=9`. I'm not aware of a simple "idle" REST API endpoint.